# Show query values in a form of list using li tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following C# code:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "my query that returns n rows";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read()) 
    {
        MyListBox.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label1.Text = "## ERROR: " + ex.Message;
}
```

On my `.aspx` page, instead of using ListBox, I want each value to be in a list item using `li` tag. I've been searching but I can't find anything if it's possible to do it using loop and if it's possible, I don't have any idea on how to do it .

Note: Honestly, as a requirement, I need to use a `li` tag for this.

Comment: `Repeater` control can help you with your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Better way is to user `DataRepeater` control.

Somewhere you have this class:

```
class Item
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    Item(string description)
    {
        this.Description = description;
    }
}
```

Here prepare a list of `objects(Item)`:

```
List<Item> items  = new List<Item>();
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    items.Add(new Item(dr.GetString(0)));
}

Repeater1.DataSource = items;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And here is the `DataRepeater` code:

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <li>'<%# Eval("Description") %>'</li>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

**Option 2:**

You can prepare custom HTML and assign it to some control to display.

Change your while loop:

```
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    MyListBox.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
}
```

to this:

```
string html = "<ul>";
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    html += "<li>" + dr.GetString(0) + "</li>";
}
html += "</ul>";

divList.InnerHTML = html;
```

Where `divList` is regular `div` you can place on `.aspx` page and add attribute `runat="server"`.

```
<div id="divList" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this one! This works! (I use the Option 1)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not be writing your data access code in code-behind. Nor you should be using `HtmlControl` objects in your data access layer. Having said that, you need to populate a collection of items using the loop and use that collection to bind with the data source attribute of an asp `HtmlControl` like **Repeater**.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `SELECT` query to this method will returns your data in DataTable:

```
public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // create a DataTable for containing your data

    OpenConnection(con); // method will open connection con

    SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
    SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(com); // fill data to the adapter
    sda.Fill(dt); // fill adapter's data to DataTable

    CloseConnection(con); // method will close connection con

    return dt;
}
```

And now you can set this as data source to DataList, Repeater, GridView, ListBox etc.

Quick example with DataList:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><% #Eval("dbValue") %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Set DataTable to data source as want:

```
DataList1.DataSource = ExecuteDataTable("SELECT * FROM myTable");
DataList1.DataBind();
```